# save state of listview clicked item

Tags: android

in my activity I have a listview contain many item and list have multichoice mode. I want to save the state of selected item of listview so when a user select items in listview and close the app and re launch app the previously selected item should already selected.thank

here my activity class.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ApkListActivity extends Activity {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;
    Editor editor;
    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    String pname = "";
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    int po;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
        .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

    /* To filter out System apps */
    for (PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
        boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
        if (!b) {
        packageList1.add(pi);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
        public int compare(PackageInfo o1, PackageInfo o2) {
        return o1.applicationInfo
            .loadLabel(getPackageManager())
            .toString()
            .compareTo(
                o2.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                    getPackageManager()).toString());
        }
    });

    apkList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.applist);
    apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList1, packageManager));
    apkList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    }



    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
        : false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that proble by using Boolean ArrayList to save the check state with the size of item.

and you also need to do that

```
if(list.get(i))
    item.setChecked(true);
else
    item.setChecked(false);
```